# Flutter: Is it possible to know if you're currently off stage?

Tags: flutter

I have a number of pages in my app wrapped in `Offstage` widgets. Each page makes use of the provider package to render based on state updates (e.g. the user does something, we make a network call and display the result).

As the pages are wrapped in `Offstage` widgets, the `build()` methods (and subsequent network calls) are called even if it's not the current page.

Is there a way inside the `build()` method to know if the widget is currently off stage (and if so, skip any expensive logic)?

I'm assuming I can work something with global state etc, but I was wondering if there was anything built-in in relation to the `Offstage` widget itself, similar to `mounted`

Comment: Is it necessary to use `Offstage` at all? maybe there's a better solution without it

Comment: It's to keep page state alive. I was looking at `Visibility` as well, but apparently it uses `Offstage` behind the scenes if you want to keep state alive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try finding the parent OffStage widget and see if the offstage property is true or false

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final offstageParent = context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<Offstage>();
    if (offstageParent != null && offstageParent.offstage == false) {
      // widget is currently offstage.
      print('offstaged child');
    } else {
      // widget is not offstage
      print('non-offstaged child');
    }
    return const Text('Example Widget');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a custom-made mechanism for the goal you wanna achieve:

First, I am declaring a new `Map<String, bool>` in a separate file alone that will hold the offStage `bool` value with the key of each class widget.

```
Map<String, bool> offStageMap = {};
```

then in the implementation of the `StatefulWidget` where the offstage widget is in:

```
 class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 ExampleWidget({super.key}) {
    widgetMapKey = runtimeType.toString();
  }
late final String widgetMapKey;
  @override
  State<ExampleWidget> createState() => _ExampleWidgetState();
}

class _ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> {
  final bool defaultIsOffStaged = false;
  bool? localStateIsOffStages;

  @override
  void initState() {
    offStageMap[widget.widgetMapKey] ??= defaultIsOffStaged;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        bool previousIsOffStaged = offStageMap[widget.widgetMapKey]!;
        setState(() {
          localStateIsOffStages =
              offStageMap[widget.widgetMapKey] = !previousIsOffStaged;
        });
      },
      child: Offstage(
        offstage: localStateIsOffStages ?? offStageMap[widget.widgetMapKey]!,
        child: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}   },
          child: Offstage(
            offstage: localStateIsOffStages ?? offStageMap[widget.widgetMapKey]!,
            child: Container(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

let me explain what this is about.

first I declared a `defaultIsOffStaged` where it should be the initial `offStage` value when nothing is saved in that map.

when that widget is inserted in the widget tree (`initState()` called), the `widget.widgetMapKey` of the `ExampleWidget` widget will be saved in that map with the value of the default one which is `defaultIsOffStaged`.

```
  offStageMap[widget.widgetMapKey] ??= defaultIsOffStaged;
```

in the offstage property o the `OffStage` widget, in this line:

```
   offstage: localStateIsOffStages ?? offStageMap[widget.widgetMapKey]!,
```

the nullable `localStateIsOffStages` will be null for the first time since it has no value yet, so `offStageMap[widget.widgetMapKey]!` which equals to `defaultIsOffStaged` will be the bool value of offstage.

until now what we have, is a map containing the key that belongs only to the `ExampleWidget` which is its `widget.widgetMapKey` with its offStage value, right?

now from all places in your app, you can get the offStage value of that widget with its `widgetMapKey` like this:

```
print(offStageMap[ExampleWidget().widgetMapKey]); // true
```

now let's say you want to change the offstage property of that widget, in my code I used a simple example of `GestureDetector`, so when we tap in the `Text("toggle offstage")` area, it toggles offStage, here is what happens:

we got the existing value in the map:
bool previousIsOffStaged = offStageMap[widget.widgetMapKey]!;

then assign the opposite of it, to that widget key in the map, and the `localStateIsOffStages` bool variable which was nullable, now it has a value.

and as normal so the state updates I wrapped it in a `SetState(() {})`

now the widget's offstage will be toggled, and every time the widget key in the map will be updated with that new value.

the `localStateIsOffStages` I declared just to hold the local state when this is happening while the `StatefulWidget` state updates.

after the `StatefulWidget` is disposed of (when you pop the route as an example) and open that route again, the `initState()` will execute but since we have now an entry in the map, it's not null so nothing will happen inside `initState()`.

the `localStateIsOffStages` will be null, so the offStage property of the `Offstage` widget will be the value from the map, which is the previous value before the widget is disposed.

that's it, from other places you can check for the offstage value of that specific widget like this:

```
 print(offStageMap[ExampleWidget().widgetMapKey])
```

you can do it for all your widget pages, so you will have a map containing the offStage values of them all.

I take it one step up, and made those methods that I guess they will help:

this will return a `List` with the pages where the value is true.

```
    List<String> offstagedPages() {
  List<String> isOffStagedPages = [];

  offStageMap.forEach((runtimeType, isOffStaged) {
    if (isOffStaged) {
      isOffStagedPages.add(runtimeType);
    }
  });
  return isOffStagedPages;
}
```

this will return a `true` if a page is off staged and `false` if not:

```
    bool isPageWidgetOffStaged(String runtimeType) {
  if (offStageMap.containsKey(runtimeType)) {
    return offStageMap[runtimeType]!;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not applicable to you, but you might be able to solve it by simply not using `Offstage`. Consider this app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool showFirst = true;

  void switchPage() {
    setState(() {
      showFirst = !showFirst;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Stack(children: [
                  Offstage(offstage: !showFirst,child: A("first", switchPage)),
                  Offstage(offstage: showFirst,child: A("second", switchPage)),
                ]))));
  }
}

class A extends StatelessWidget {
  final String t;
  final Function onTap;
  const A(this.t, this.onTap, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('$t is building');
    return TextButton(onPressed: ()=> onTap(), child: Text(t));
  }
}
```

You will notice by the prints that both pages are build. But if you rewrite it like this without `Offstage`, only the visible one is build:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Stack(children: [
                  if (showFirst) A("first", switchPage),
                  if (!showFirst)  A("second", switchPage),
                ]))));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but - correct me if I'm wrong - this doesn't keep page state alive? So if each page has sub navigation, you would lose your position etc

Comment: @divillysausages ah yeah, it probably doesn't keep the state alive no

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just keep state alive your pages , you can use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html , you may check this blog for example usage, https://medium.com/manabie/flutter-simple-cheatsheet-4370a68f98b3

Comment: That's interesting, though the line `their build methods must call super.build (though the return value should be ignored)` would imply that `build()` is called anyway, just that it's not used?

Comment: I appreciate the answer, btw, though my question is more "how can I know if I'm off stage" rather than "how can I keep state alive"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Navigator, you can just extends NavigatorObserver. Then you will get didpush and didpop, use state to manage elementlifecycle, you will get page onPause and onResume fun.